# E ImportError: cannot import name '_legacy_validators' from 'jsonschema'

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to run pytest on multiple files using make unittest:

```
unittest:
    echo "Running unit tests..."
    ./venv/bin/pytest --tb=long -rafs -vvv --cov=$(NAME) --cov-report term-missing tests/ --ignore tests/pcs_historic_view
    echo "Completed Running unit tests..."
```

pytest=5.3.5

jsonschema=4.19.2

I tried to upgrade the jsonschema module using:

```
pip install --upgrade jsonschema
```

I was hoping it would resolve the issue, because I thought it was caused by an outdated python package.